# Delete checked rows from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview that I have added an ItemTemplate to display a checkbox for each row. I am trying to simply delete the rows checked in the code behind file. My issue is that my code behind does not detect the checkbox. It is very strange because I feel like I haven't changed anything, but the code no longer works (it worked as of two days ago, but locally saved these changes - did not upload to TFS).

GridView (EDITED TO INCLUDE BINDING):

```
  <%--Data Grid--%>
<asp:GridView ID="Grid_Recipe" CssClass="gridMain" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Grid_Recipe_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Recipe_ID" DataSourceID="DataSource_Grid_Unfiltered" EnableViewState="True" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" HorizontalAlign="Center">

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCFFFF" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Edit" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select"> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:CheckBox ID="deleteCheckbox" runat="server" /> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Recipe_ID" HeaderText="Recipe_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Recipe_ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Difficulty" HeaderText="Difficulty" SortExpression="Difficulty" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Meal" HeaderText="Meal" SortExpression="Meal" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cook_Time" HeaderText="Cook Time" SortExpression="Cook_Time" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Directions" HeaderText="Directions" SortExpression="Directions" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0096D6" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</asp:GridView>

<%--Delete Button--%>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="deleteButton" Text="Delete Checked" OnClick="DeleteRows" />


<%--Data Sources--%>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Meal_Filter" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LYNNAU_ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Meal] FROM [Recipe]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource_Grid_Unfiltered" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LYNNAU_ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Recipe]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Recipe] SET [Name] = @Name, [Difficulty] = @Difficulty, [Meal] = @Meal, [Cook_Time] = @Cook_Time, [Directions] = @Directions WHERE [Recipe_ID] = @Recipe_ID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recipe_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Difficulty" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Meal" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Cook_Time" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Directions" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recipe_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource_Grid_Meal" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LYNNAU_ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Recipe] WHERE ([Meal] = @Meal)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Recipe] SET [Name] = @Name, [Difficulty] = @Difficulty, [Meal] = @Meal, [Cook_Time] = @Cook_Time, [Directions] = @Directions WHERE [Recipe_ID] = @Recipe_ID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recipe_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Meal_DDL" Name="Meal" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Difficulty" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Meal" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Cook_Time" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Directions" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Recipe_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
protected void DeleteRows(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dbCRUD delete = new dbCRUD();
    foreach(GridViewRow grd in Grid_Recipe.Rows)
    {
        if(grd.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if((grd.FindControl("deleteCheckbox") as CheckBox).Checked)
            {
                string id = Grid_Recipe.DataKeys[grd.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                //int intID = Convert.ToInt32(Grid_Recipe.SelectedDataKey.Value);
                int intID = int.Parse(id);
                if(delete.DeleteRecord(intID) == 1)
                {
                    resultsDelete.Text = "SQL Exception";
                    resultsDelete.Visible = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if(delete.DeleteRecord(intID) == 2)
                {
                    resultsDelete.Text = "Non SQL Exception";
                    resultsDelete.Visible = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    resultsDelete.Text = "Record(s) deleted";
                    resultsDelete.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anything in my code that would prevent the checkbox from being detected? I've put a breakpoint on the method and I get to where it checks validation for the checkbox, but after it iterates through every row, no rows are detected. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So all checkboxes are found, but neither is checked, right? In this case can you show the code for grid view binding, preferably the whole page event handler where this happens?

Comment: Just added the source controls. I tried to bind the data to the grid if the page is post back because my thinking was that the db would already be updated, but that could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like server side it's not going to know anything about your `GridView` because you have `EnableViewState="False"` set.

Set that to `true` and see if it helps.  If not check how you are binding the `GridView` and make sure you are not rebinding it again to a `null` value in your `Page_Load` or something before the `DeleteRows` function runs.  Post how you bind as that will help diagnose the issue.

I have also posted recently an answer to a similar question that you can find here:
[iterate through gridview rows on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121248/iterate-through-gridview-rows-on-button-click/)

Comment: Changed EnableViewState to true and it did not have an effect. I did post the data source controls in an edit to my original question.

Comment: I removed the PostBack grid binding and it seems to have fixed my issue. I added a grid binding after the record was deleted but within my DeleteRows method and that has the functionality working properly. On to another issue, but thanks for the help!